# How to calculate Annual Variance on Monthly basis?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

Am new to Power BI and appreciate help on DAX for this requirement:

I have a FY slicer (July-June) in my Power BI reports and wants to show monthly trending across different FY years. Target data is structured like this in a table:

Dates             |       Target

30-06-2018        |        34000

30-07-2018        |        34000

30-08-2018        |        34000

**********        |        *****

30-06-2019        |        30000

30-07-2019        |        30000

**********         |      ******

I need to calculate annual variance with below formula to get monthly baseline for next year(2019), then calculate cumulative reduction variance across July-June:

('Target of 30-06-2018') - ('Target of 30-06-2019')/ 12

Dates are linked to another DATE table, which has Financial year and Financial month columns.

Thanks so much in advance for the help!!
Anita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the DAX PARALLELPERIOD

```
PARALLELPERIOD(<dates>,<number_of_intervals>,<interval>)
```

The documentation gives a perfect example:

```
 = CALCULATE(SUM(InternetSales_USD[SalesAmount_USD]), PARALLELPERIOD(DateTime[DateKey],-1,year))
```

So your calculation will something like:

```
   = (
      CALCULATE(SUM(TargetTable[Target])) - 
      CALCULATE(SUM(TargetTable[Target]), PARALLELPERIOD(Dates[Date],-1,year))
     ) / 12
```

If you want monthly variance, then you need to ensure that Dates[Date] is filtered at a grain to return a table of dates for the entire target month.

You can find a [great blog on it here](https://databear.com/power-bi-dax-sameperiodlastyear-paralellperiod-and-dateadd/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Really appreciate the blog link!!

Comment: My pleasure @Anita

Answer (score 0):

For next year, I got June Baseline value with SAMPLEPERIODLASTYEAR.

1: Last year value = CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE (TargetTable[Target]),
SAMPLEPERIODLASTYEAR (Dates[Date]))

2: Base Target = IF (MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(TargetTable[Dates])=6, DIVIDE ([Last year value]-SELECTEDVALUE (TargetTable[Target]), 12))

Still need to figure out Cumulative monthly variance across next financial year?